# A person who reads is a "reader". What is a person who peeks called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a name for a person who peeks?

I have tried looking up merriam-webster for the term "peeker" (as I expected this is a real word), to no avail.

Comment: What is the context?  Peeking around a corner, peeking ahead in a novel, peeking in someone's window?  An example sentence of how you intend to use the word would be helpful.

Comment: *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.* In this case, a (very unusual) candidate word has already been proposed by OP, but unless we know the *full context*, it's not realistic to expect us to pronounce on whether or not that word might be "suitable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call such a person a *peeker* because English would allow this usage, that is the adding of *-er* to most verbs to refer to a person who does the action of the verb.

However there is the word *[peeper](http://www.onelook.com/?w=peeper&ls=a)* which is often used. And we have an idiom about a *[peeping Tom](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peeping-tom)*. (Although I see now from [your comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299103/a-person-who-reads-is-a-reader-what-is-a-person-who-peeks-called/299106#comment672651_299104) that you wish to avoid this word.)

You could get a better answer if you provided a sentence in which you wish to use *'peeker'*.

Comment: thanx, i cannot really provide a sentence - the usage is within a program code (i'm a programmer). this makes a lot of sense though.

Comment: @EliranMalka As GoDucks said, it is a 'legal' creation of a word 'peeker', it's just that it doing so doesn't always work well with intransitive verbs (it works sometimes, like 'runner', but often not, like 'The wound oozes' -> '*the wound is an oozer', that just doesn't sound right, even though it is 'legal'.

Comment: @Eliran: Note that *to peek* has a very specific sense in programming contexts. If you "peek" a keypress, for example, that's not the same as ***reading*** the keypress (because repeatedly *peeking* always returns the same keypress value, whereas each time you *read*, you get the ***next*** keypress). Given that background context, it would be perfectly acceptable to refer to a "peeker function" (that non-destructively reads some value). The same principle might apply to a process checking whether Schrodinger's cat is still alive, without "collapsing the wave function", by one interpretation.

Comment: @Mitch 'This wound is a real **oozer**. It just keeps on *oozing* away all day long' seems perfectly natural to me. Although I certainly did not intend to write a dissertation about *which verbs* one can add *-er* to, which is why I wrote *most*. Perhaps a more accurate qualifier would have been *many*. You are free to write a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Peeker" isn't a word.  One who peeks could be a "peeper."

Comment: Just because [peeker](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22peeker%22#q=%22the+peeker%22&tbm=bks&start=10) isn't a particularly common usage doesn't make it *not a "word"*. To *peek* and *peep* are different words, with different connotations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers i agree, a *peeper* has a fairly different connotation, which i'm trying to avoid (well, hopefully).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, in this context both  words mean the same thing: " To look slyly, or with the eyes half closed, or through a crevice; to peep." — Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary 1913: [Peek](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=peek&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on). Yes, I must admit that, for whatever reason, Peep is the preferred form in some contexts, esp. the lewder ones but I think it should be noted that peek is certainly not immune from any of Peep's connotations and the visa-versa also applies.

Comment: @Tonepoet: In *what* context? I have closevoted specifically because *OP **hasn't** provided an exact context* in the question text. I've [guessed in a comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299103/a-person-who-reads-is-a-reader-what-is-a-person-who-peeks-called/299104?noredirect=1#comment672659_299106) what that context might be, and to my mind if my guess is correct then there's no possibility of treating *peek/peep* as "synonymous".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, by that I mean [Peep](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=peep&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) has meanings other than to look. It can be an onomatopoeia for the sounds a chick makes and peeper can be a synonym for eye but the only sense of the word where the two would be compared is taking a sly look, esp. through a crevice. That's all.

Comment: @Tonepoet: oic. Yes, *taking a **sly** look, esp. through a **crevice*** does apply to both words in most contexts. But the specific implication of *not advancing a "read" pointer* in a computer datastream being "peeked" certainly doesn't normally attach to "peeping".